# Jupyter notebook looks for modules in the wrong place

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I use Anaconda to start Jupyter notebook. 
However, since this week, I get the error that Jupyter cannot find Mathplotlib, but it is look in the wrong directory, I think.

[image]

I think it should look in a directory under'Anaconda3'? The problems started when I installed Python again, I think. It's as if there are two versions installled and Jupiter Notebook cannot find my libraries anymore.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Anaconda navigator may fix the issue!

Comment: I have reinstalled Anaconda, but to no avail.
Then I renamed the folder (that was in the screenshot) so Jupiter notebook couldn't look for python there anymore. And that helped. Jupiter notebook doesn't give me the error anymore.